# How to retrieve data in nodejs from post api with vuejs

Tags: node.js, api, post, vue.js

I am trying to write a post api in nodejs and using vuejs as front end frame work and using vue-resource to access apis . This is my submit function on the front end side.

```
validateBeforeSubmit() {
        var self = this;

        this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => {
          if (result) {
            self.data = self.name;
            console.log(this.data)
            this.$http.post('/api/add_level',self.data).then(function(res){
              this.status = res.body
              console.log(this.status);
            this.largeModal=false;
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            alert('From Submitted!');


            })
            return;

          }
```

This my code on the server side.

```
app.post('/api/add_level',function(req,res,err,data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a varible `var self = this` pointing the correct vue instancre , then why are you using `this` again in you callback of the vue-resource's post request

Use `self` every when in the method wherever you want o reference the vue instance. This is possible due to the concept of  [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

so change your code to:

```
    this.$validator.validateAll().then(function(result) {
      if (result) {
        self.data = self.name;
        console.log(this.data)
        this.$http.post('/api/add_level',self.data).then(function(res){
          self.status = res.body
          console.log(self.status);
        self.largeModal=false;
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        alert('From Submitted!');


        })
        return;

      }
```

**Note**

I recommend you use normal function syntax and make use of closures or use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as they bind `this` lexically. Do not mix them up and use simultaneously